# Entity Framework context in context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i have a context class like below,i want to log all db operation where another database,using a DbContext in another DbContext?is it a problem?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SiteUser> SiteUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SystemLanguage> SystemLanguages { get; set; }

    public int SaveChanges(string userId)
    {
        LogContext logDB = new LogContext();

        var entries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added || 
                p.State == EntityState.Deleted || 
                p.State == EntityState.Modified);

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            foreach (AuditLog log in
                GetAuditRecordsForChange(entry, userId))
            {
                logDB.AuditLogs.Add(log);
            }
        }

        logDB.SaveChanges();

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is not a problem, since you can easily create a connection to another database (or even open multiple connections to the same database), which is what the `DbContext` is doing under the covers.